# Using Twitter Bootstrap responsive design to make column header into field labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2. I'm using the fluid grid system to display tabular data with column headers. When the user resizes the browser down to the size of a phone viewport and the columns collapse down into one column I'd like to hide the column headers and instead show labels next to each field for each row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.hidden-phone
.hidden-tablet
.hidden-desktop

class tags will hide stuff in the view you want.

and like-wise

.visible-phone is the other way around